# ActiveRecord string primary key used in foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

It's possible to override ActiveRecord's primary key to be a string, and have a custom type like:

```
create_table :system_currencies, :primary_key => 'iso_code' do |t|
      t.column :iso_code, :string, :limit => 3
end
```

But how to use this table/model in other models that have references to it?
For references ActiveRecord always expects the foreign key column to end with "_id" and to be an integer value.

Is it true? 
How to do a reference to such SystemCurrency model from an Order model in the situation when SystemCurrency uses string iso_code as primary key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the primary key on a join. For example:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :system_currency, :primary_key => "iso_code"
end
```

More information can be found in the Rails API at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to

Is this what you are after or have I misunderstood your question?